# How to pass variables from windows application to asp website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-3.0, csharpcodeprovider

I am trying to build a desktop interface for my my website and want to pass variable to the asp sever.but couldn't find a proper way to pass these values more concisely  i want to pass variables from separate window form application to a separate asp server.I don't want to  pass values to web browser but to directly them to a web server.

Comment: What values ? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to get values in window form, from user and want to perform extract and insert operation using these values, in the database of an asp website.

Comment: Make changes to accept `QueryString` in your asp.net application and send request to that `URL` with `QueryString` from `winforms` application

Comment: would you please provide, any sample code or any reference link for it.

Answer (score 3):

In your website, make an API controller that will take your desktop data as a POST request.

From your client, you can then pass data easily, i.e. by serializing to JSON before sending.

Comment: I am a beginner and don't have enough knowledge. i am working on my collage project please would you provide me some detail and references about these things like Jason and API controller..